# iTextSharp pdf header

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using ItextSharp to create PDF documents, but I have a problem to create an header table that is repeated on each page.

I have a function that creates the layout of this table in this way:

```
public PdfPTable createTabHeader()
    {
        PdfPTable tableIntestazione = new PdfPTable(2);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rendicontazione"));
        cell.Border = 0;
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
        cell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        cell.PaddingTop = 45;
        tableIntestazione.AddCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        iTextSharp.text.Image imgLogo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgLogo"]);
        imgLogo.ScalePercent(10);
        imgLogo.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        cell.AddElement(imgLogo);
        cell.Border = 0;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
        cell.BorderColorBottom = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        tableIntestazione.AddCell(cell);
        tableIntestazione.HeaderRows = 1;
        return tableIntestazione;
    }
```

I read on the web that the property "HeaderRows" permits to show the table header on each page, but in my case it totally hides this table.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that no table is shown: you are creating a table with two columns to which you are adding two cells. This means you have a table consisting of *a single row*. You define this row as the header row. Now you have a table with *a single header row and no body rows*. As there are no body rows, the header row isn't rendered. It doesn't make sense to have a table with a header and no data.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for the answer. Yes i know that my table is composed by one row...and i would like that this row is repeated on each page of the pdf document. Is it possible?

Thank you very much Cinzia

Comment: In that case, you're not looking for a table with a header, you are looking for a page event, aren't you?

Comment: Hi Bruno,
maybe i have not been too precise to explain my problem, but your first answer has illuminated me :) :) :)  I have a pdf document with some tables; the first one should be the header of the document. If i use all the tables singularly, it's not possible to use the "HeaderRows" attribute  but if i include all the tables into a main table and i set to this the attribute "HeaderRows = 1" i have the first row like the header of the document and it is repetead on each pages. 

Thank you for the help
Cinzia